# Best Bractice To Update The Aggregated Objects in Elastic search, Microservices

Tags: c#, sql-server, elasticsearch, microservices

I have two microservices one of them called **Home** containes metadata info about the home including FK from another microservice called **Address**

I am using SQL Server to store the entity records

- HomeEntity( Represent Table in DB) in **Home microservice** contains columns `->` `Id, AddressId(FK), price`
- AddressEntity(Represent Table in DB) in **Address microservice** contains columns `->` `Id, Street, ZipCode`

I am using Elastic search to store the Address in a separate index in **Home microservice** and this index always up to date since the Address MS publishes a message on change or on add address.

And I have  `Get` endpoint API in Home microservice it must return smth like

```
Home : {
Id: 1,
price : 3000,
Address :{
   id: 1,
   street: "blabla",
   zibcode : 12345

  }
}
```

So I stored them Aggregated in another index in elastic search called **HomeIndex**

**My problem** when one of the addresses becomes updated what is the best practice to update all documents that attached to the same Address **HomeIndex**.

currently, I'm using [_update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) is there any way to keep  **HomeIndex** up to date with the latest Address changes?

Comment: for me the _update_by_query is the best practice for your use case. You will have very few Home with the same address so update by query should be very quick

Comment: I have another case with same scenario but it  could be effect 100k or more document in the index!

Comment: You can, if your use case really match, think about parent child . Usually it;s not a good practice. But if you have a large cardinality and a lot of updates on the wrong side, it can be the good solution https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/parent-child-relationships.html